# Bootstrap: Extra Space in Collapsed Navbar between the brand name and the 3 Horizontal bars drop-down button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm creating a navbar-fixed-top for my page and when the navbar is collapsed (e.g. for small viewports), there is extra space between the "Brand" name and the expand menu icon.

Here is a picture of what is happening:
[Extra Space in Collapsed Navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjK3C.png)

And here's my navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class ="container">
        <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a></div>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navTop">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navTop" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px;">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"
                            style="padding-bottom: 7px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me figure out how to remove the extra space? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `navbar-header` should enclose the button, it currently ends before the button starts. Also, (depending on your use case) the form doesnt need to be inside a `ul` and causes display issues if it is actually. See [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

See working Example Snippet.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navTop">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navTop">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and fixed my issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

see if you have the following. Hope it helps

```
.navbar-brand {float: left;}  and .navbar-toggle{float: right;}
```